# Install OpenGL / Nvidia OpenGL whose version is higher than 4.4

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, opengl

I'm sorry to ask such a question, but I am bothered by this question for more than two weeks.
All the information is from the GPU server, (4 NVIDIA 3090 GPUs).
To check the OpenGL Version, `sudo glxinfo | grep OpenGL`, following is the Output:

```
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Also, I can get some information from the GUI, settings->detials->Graphics: `llvmpipe(LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits)`.

When I input `nvidia-smi`, I can get the correct information, but I have no idea why there are 5MiB cost.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 455.38       Driver Version: 455.38       CUDA Version: 11.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 3090    Off  | 00000000:1A:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   24C    P8     6W / 350W |      5MiB / 24268MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce RTX 3090    Off  | 00000000:3E:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   22C    P8    10W / 350W |      5MiB / 24268MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce RTX 3090    Off  | 00000000:89:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   22C    P8     6W / 350W |      5MiB / 24268MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  GeForce RTX 3090    Off  | 00000000:B1:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   23C    P8    10W / 350W |      5MiB / 24268MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2318      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      2318      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    2   N/A  N/A      2318      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    3   N/A  N/A      2318      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

When I input `lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"`, I don't know whether this is right. The output is listed following:

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family (rev 41)
        Subsystem: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family
        Kernel driver in use: ast
--
1a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2204 (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 3881
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
--
3e:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2204 (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 3881
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
--
89:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2204 (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 3881
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
--
b1:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2204 (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 3881
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

When I input `prime-select query`, the output is `nvidia`

When I input `nvidia-settings` and access to the NVIDIA settings X server, I cannot see the `prime profile`, which means I can't switch the GPU.

I have tested installing nvidia driver in many ways.
(1)`software and update`: uninstall current drivers and install or update the nvidia driver from the GUI, then reboot my server.
(2)`download the *.run files`: both `sudo ./*.run` with/without `--no_opengl_files` have been tried. Without this command, I will get the `login loop` problem.
(3) `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` and `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`.
All above methods do not help me out.

I have tested above methods in a 4*1080Ti GPU server as well. Their situation exists the same.

I really appreciate it if someone can help me.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu, which release?

Comment: The 3090 server: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-58-generic x86_64)                          The 1080Ti server: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-101-generic x86_64)